# Shortcodes get wrapped with p tags

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, shortcode

I would like to insert some shortcodes in the wordpress editor (v 3.3+)

The string looks like

```
[a_col]<p>some text or other stuff</p>[/a_col]
```

which is fine but if i use this line in JS

```
tinyMCE.get('content').setContent(string);
```

my shortcodes get surrounded by p tags which looks like

```
<p>[a_col]</p><p>some text or other stuff</p><p>[/a_col]</p>
```

I really don't like to touch native functions. Maybe there is a different solution to insert content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

the shortcode function returns

```
<div class="col a">'.preg_replace('#^<\/p>|<p>$#', '', do_shortcode($content)).'</div>
```

this removes all unwanted p tags

Answer (score 0):

If you were to add_filter on 'the_content', you could probably parse the

tags out:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: Don't like to do it serverside. I would like to send the correct markup on a submit action

Answer (score 0):

When in the "editor"  switch to HTML mode from tinymce mode.  That way it's not converting what you have in the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in Wordpress version 2.5.1 see the shortcode API for further details